# Prove that each tree $T=(V,E)$ with $|V| \geq 2$ contains at least $2$ leaves.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, trees

I'm not sure if this lemma has a name or not but here goes:

> Every tree $T=(V,E)$ with $|V| \geq 2$ contains at least $2$ leaves.

The proof for this relies on the fact that if we start with only $2$ nodes, $v_1,v_2 \in V$, then we have an $e \in E$, which connects $v_1$ and $v_2$, then $T$ has $2$ leaves. If we have more than $2$ nodes, then we can pick either $v_1$ or $v_2$ and go in either direction. If we go in the direction of $v_1$ and it is not an end node, then we go to the succeeding node. If that is an end node, then we have one leaf. However, since we didn't move in the direction of $v_2$, we have a total of $2$ leaves. We can repeat this for any number of nodes on either side.

However, how can we argue that it's possible for there to be more than $2$ leaves?

Comment: To show that it’s **possible** to have more than $2$ leaves, you need only give an example; the smallest such example has $4$ nodes and $3$ leaves.

Comment: But that would mean I would also have to give an example of a tree which has $4$ leaves, $5$ leaves and so on. Isn’t that not allowed?

Comment: It’s not clear to me exactly what you’re trying to show. Are you trying to show that for each integer $n\ge 2$ there is a tree with $n$ leaves? If that **is** what you want, just let $V=\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ and $E=\big\{\{0,k\}:1\le k\le n\big\}$.

Comment: Ah I seem to have confused the two things. So to prove that any tree has at least $2$ leaves, it’s enough to show that it has $2$ leaves. Or?

Comment: Yes, to prove that any tree has at least $2$ leaves, it’s enough to show that it cannot have $0$ or $1$. The moment that you’ve shown that there must be **at least** $2$, you’re done.